# Open CSV file without converting text to formula

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have a CSV file filled mostly with text and when I open it with Excel, some cells are interpreted as formulas and have the value `#NAME?` in them.

It comes from the fact that those cells start with a "-" followed by a letter. Those cells actually contain an enumeration on multiple lines.

To reproduce this issue, you could simply type the following in a cell; save it as a CSV file; close it; and reopen it.

> '-a

The apostrophe is important here as it tells Excel to treat the content of the cell as a string and not a formula. However, when reopening the CSV this apostrophe will be gone and replaced by an equal sign, hence we get the `#NAME?` error.

So, I thought of implementing a macro that would loop through the cells in the CSV file right after it was open to fix that issue by removing the equal sign that gets added by Excel:

```
Sub PostCsvOpenConvertToString()
'PURPOSE: Convert all #NAME (caused by formula automatic conversion back) to a string.
'INSTRUCTION: Run right after opening the CSV file.

    Dim CsvFile As Workbook
    Set CsvFile = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = CsvFile.Sheets(1)

    Dim CellsValue() As Variant
    CellsValue = ws.UsedRange.Value2

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(CellsValue, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(CellsValue, 2)

            If CVErr(CellsValue(i, j)) = CVErr(xlErrName) Then
                Dim CellFormula As String
                CellFormula = ws.UsedRange.Cells(i, j).Formula
                If Left$(CellFormula, 1) = "=" Then
                    ws.UsedRange.Cells(i, j).Formula = Right$(CellFormula, Len(CellFormula) - 1)
                End If
            End If

        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

This approach works, but what I would like to know is if there is a more straightforward approach. Is there a way to save the file so that Excel won't convert it to a formula when it gets reopened?

Or perhaps, is there a way to open the CSV so that Excel won't convert the cells to a formula?

I know I could go to **Data > Get and Transform Data > From Text/CSV**. The only thing is that it creates a table (which I don't want) and I'm not used to write those queries in VBA. So, if I can avoid it I would prefer, but if it's the only solution I'll consider it.

Note: It's good to know that this behavior is the same for all the other letters in the alphabet except C and R which probably has something to do with R1C1-style references.

Comment: What you have is a poorly formatted CSV file. Anything that is text should have double quotes around it. If possible, put your efforts into fixing the CSV.

Comment: @DeanOC - Yeah, that's one way to do it. I would still have to remove the double quotes afterwards since they don't go away when opening the CSV file normally, but that is a valid answer (feel free to post it).

Comment: If you don't want the table, use the Legacy import wizard.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - It's good to know this exists, thanks! However, I still get a #NAME? error when I use the [Legacy import wizard](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-import-wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857#ID0EAAEAAA=Newer_versions).

Comment: Did you select `Text` as the column type?  I do not get that error.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I hadn't (I'm weirdly used to skip that part). Selecting Text as the column type does indeed solve the issue and doesn't create a table. Thanks! 
Also feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: @DeanOC You get the same error in Excel even with the double-quotes. Create a text file, put `"-a"` in it, save it with a .csv extension, and open it in Excel, and you will see the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks again to [Ron Rosenfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2872922/ron-rosenfeld) for providing this answer in the comments. I'm just going to reproduce it here with some details, so I can mark this question as answered.

---

To avoid inserting the table while importing a CSV from the `Data > Get Data` section, it is possible to use the [Text Import Wizard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-import-wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#ID0EAAEAAA=Newer_versions) that can be added to the options available.

[image]

Then, make sure in Step 3 to indicate that the data is Text:

[image]